# PHP Contact form in website not sending Japanese characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I am using a simple php contact form that sends to an email, but when I want it to send Japanese characters, the email I receive from the form displays those characters in strange Greek-looking code.  I assume there is some way to specify in the php form that I am using UTF-8, but I am not sure where or what to put to let the characters display as Japanese.  Below is the code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
        $email_to = "abc@abc.com";
        $email_subject = "Contact Form";

        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
        $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {
            $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
            return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
```

Comment: Stripped excessive whitespace - please take care to format your code without so much space ;)

Comment: ah thanks! I'm still getting used to it!